# Set text in Active Conversation in iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage-extension

I wrote some code to add text to the Messages.app input field  in my iMessage extension.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"didSelect called");
    NSLog(@"%d", 1);
    [[self activeConversation] insertText:@"https://google.com" completionHandler:^(NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error happened");
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    NSLog(@"%d", 2);
}
```

The strange part is that all of the normal logs are happening. The app will log "didSelect called", "1" and "2". However, the message - the Google url - isn't being inserted, and the error logs aren't being shown. So I don't really have a clue as to what's going wrong. Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does [self activeConversation] != nil?

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss I added `NSLog(@"self.activeConversation != nil: %d", (self.activeConversation != nil));`, which returned 0. Turns out, it is indeed nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**

1. Send correct reference from `MessagesViewController` to your view controller.
2. Check `activeConversation` value for nil:

---

```
if ([self activeConversation] != nil) {
    [[self activeConversation] insertText:@"Some text" completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Conversation is nil");
}
```

**Solution #2**

1. Create `Singleton` in `iMessage` extension name space.
2. In `MessagesViewController` in `- (void)viewDidLoad` setup reference to
   your `MSConversation`: `[[Conversation shared] activeConversation] = [self activeConversation];`
3. Use `[[Conversation shared] activeConversation] insertText: .... ];`
   for sending messages from any controllers.

Comment: But, the code I'm running is inside the `MSMessagesAppViewController`, so `activeConversation` shouldn't even be `nil`. That's the problem here, I think.

Comment: @user4992124 Try to run the test project: [AudioMessages](https://github.com/sergVn/AudioMessages)

Comment: @user4992124 I had the same issue. The problem is not that your view controller does not conform to `MSMessagesAppViewController`, but that you can't access `activeConversation` outside of your root view controller (the first view controller that is initialized when your iMessage extension is started).